# UFW allow not working as expected

Tags: firewall, nginx, ufw

I've created an Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS) virtual machine in the [Oracle Cloud](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/compute/virtual-machines.html). It comes with UFW installed. I would like the VM to run a Nginx web server. According to many blog posts, I could just say execute `ufw allow "Nginx Full"` or `sudo ufw allow 80`. I did both, just to be sure...

The output of `sudo ufw status verbose` is now:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

This seems to make sense. However, port 80 is still not reachable from the outside world.

Any ideas for troubleshooting?

Comment: It looks like you have added both. You can remove lines 3 and 6. Are you sure you are using the public facing IP address to reach the web server?

Comment: Please see my question and my answer at https://superuser.com/questions/1487012/no-route-to-host-when-trying-to-connect-to-a-tcp-service-on-an-oracle-cloud-in/1487039 You may have to use *iptables*

Comment: The difference between line 3 and 6 is that the former refers to IPv4, while the latter refers to IPv6. So I think they don't overlap. Also, I'm using the public IP for connecting.

Comment: I installed the firewalld package, and added the individual ports (refer to https://superuser.com/a/1491549/238226). That works, nginx is now reachable from the outside world! Thanks, @FedonKadifeli!

Comment: Lines 3 does the same thing line 2 already does, opens port 80 for IPv4 traffic. Similarly Line 6 does the same thing line 5 does, opens port 80 for IPv6 traffic